# How to put multiple fields on the same line (playframework)

Tags: playframework

In Play's tutorial, there's this piece of code:

```
<ul>
    @for(task <- tasks) {
        <li>
            @task.label

            @form(routes.Application.deleteTask(task.id)) {
                <input type="submit" value="Delete">
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Which resulted in this: 
[image]

I'm wondering if it's possible to make the button "Delete" stay right next to the task's label. I've tried multiple ways but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oversimplified solution: `form {display: inline;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this task Play generates just... HTML code, so refactor it as desired ie. by wrapping the rows in the HTML `table` instead of `ul` list or use CSS for floating the elements and that's all.

Comment: Oh come on, it's 2013. Don't recommend a `<table>` to display non-tabular data. You're better than that! :)

Comment: @Carsten, that's not quite truth :) ofc. nowadays using tables for building layouts is very old-school way - but represanting tabular data (and entries from some listings are tabular) is still allowed :)

Comment: @biesior I disagree, although my view might not be objective. I only regard data as tabular if its display has more than one column and more than one row. This also applies to data which has _the possibility_ to have more than one column/row, but just happens not to have it. In this case, though, there is only one piece of data per item, the task's name, which makes it the perfekt candidate for a list and not a table. (I know, this is just fussing about details. Maybe we should move this to chat. Do we even have a chat?)

Comment: @Carsten I agree but the buttons are regarded as the 2nd column no? Personally I like tables because it's easy...